# UICollectionView Segues and Multiple Selection on same UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, multipleselection

I have a UICollectionView. If I touch a cell, it triggers a segue. If "trash" or "save" is enabled, then users should be able to touch cells to add to an array that is processed for the corresponding action.

When trash/save is enabled, the segue triggers instead of allowing multiple selection. How do I do this so that I can have 2 modes: 1 for segues and 1 for multiple selection.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (self.saveEnabled == YES) {
        NSArray *itemsToDelete = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];

        [self.itemsArray addObjectsFromArray:itemsToDelete];
    }

    else if (self.trashEnabled == YES) {
        NSArray *itemsToDelete = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
        [self.itemsArray addObjectsFromArray:itemsToDelete];
    }
    else{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"collectionUnwind" sender:self];

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want multiple selection in uicollectionview cell

Answer (score 1):

The key step is that you need return false in shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier when in multi-selection mode.

Here is how I do this in swift:

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return !self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection
}
```

And I switch between single-select and multi-select mode with long press, you can use button to do the same.

```
func setupLongPressGesture() {
    let longPressGesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongPress))
    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.0 // 1 second press
    longPressGesture.delegate = self
    self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
}

@objc func handleLongPress(_ gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
        self.labelState.text = "multiple selection enabled"
    } else if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
        self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = !self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection
    }
}
```

I refer to the tutorial here: https://www.appcoda.com/ios-collection-view-tutorial/

Comment: Please interpret the tutorial you are linking

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you really want. Tell us exactly what you do (buttons) and in which order to delete (or save) multiple cells.

By the way did you enable multiple selection on your collection view ?

```
[self.collectionView setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
```

EDIT :

In your storyboard, just add a segue with "collectionUnwind" identifier from your current ViewController (and not the cells of its CollectionView) to the new ViewController you want to push. If you link it to the cells, Xcode will assume you need the new ViewController to be pushed on every cell selection.

Your current code should do the rest.

Comment: I did set allowsMultipleSelection to YES. The issue is that when user touches cell, the segue triggers and not the code to add the indexPaths to the array.

Comment: Did you set the segue in your storyboard ? Because if you did, it will be triggered by every time you select a cell, no matter what code you put in the didSelect

Comment: Yeah, it's in storyboard as an unwind segue.

Comment: Make sure that in your storyboard it is defined on your viewcontroller and not on cells of your collectionview.

Comment: OK, then what? Can you please edit your answer and give full solution from clicking on cell to unwind? If it works I will accept.